# How to find installation directory of Apache Spark package in Homebrew?

Tags: macos, apache-spark, homebrew

I installed spark on my mac with homebrew.  I'm trying to find the directory where I installed it.  I've tried googling it but I'm not having much luck.  It doesn't seem like it should be that tricky.  Can anyone please tell me what I need to run in mac terminal or from spark shell to find the installation directory for spark?

Update:

Code:

```
brew info apache-spark
```

Output:

```
apache-spark: stable 2.3.2, HEAD
Engine for large-scale data processing
https://spark.apache.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.3.2 (1,058 files, 244.6MB) *
  Built from source on 2018-10-30 at 14:16:30
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/apache-spark.rb
==> Requirements
Required: java = 1.8 ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Analytics
install: 4,534 (30 days), 14,340 (90 days), 56,698 (365 days)
install_on_request: 4,263 (30 days), 13,490 (90 days), 51,876 (365 days)
build_error: 0 (30 days)
```

code:

```
which spark-shell
```

Output:

```
/Users/sshields/anaconda2/bin/spark-shell
```

Comment: Did you look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/253128/what-should-i-do-to-fix-homebrew?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should use `brew info apache-spark` and it will include the path in the output if you `brew install` it (I did not so it's not in the output below)

```
$ brew info apache-spark
apache-spark: stable 2.3.2, HEAD
Engine for large-scale data processing
https://spark.apache.org/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/apache-spark.rb
==> Requirements
Required: java = 1.8 ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Analytics
install: 4,534 (30 days), 14,340 (90 days), 56,698 (365 days)
install_on_request: 4,263 (30 days), 13,490 (90 days), 51,876 (365 days)
build_error: 0 (30 days)
```

From the [website](https://brew.sh/):

> Homebrew installs packages to their own directory and then symlinks their files into /usr/local.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me so quickly.  Your suggestion works.  I've added an update to my original post with the output.  I noticed also if I use "which spark-shell" I get a different directory.  Does that mean I have two spark environments installed?

Comment: @user3476463 Yes. Anaconda is something from Python dev envs. No experience with it. BTW Please accept the answer if worked for you. Thanks.

Comment: for me it's `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/apache-spark/3.5.0`

Answer (score 2):

By default, Homebrew install all packages into the following directory in all versions of Mac OS. You can easily find home of maven, fish, wget, apache-spark etc at below location

```
/usr/local/Cellar/
```